# saving form data and sessions

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'm currently developing a small app, which is basically a form to capture data.

I'm having a small problem though, with the form validation.

The URLs are in the form of `http://www.example.com/123456` or `http://www.example.com/234567`, so anything with a numeric value.

All this is fine, but because these number do not represent an id of a record in my db, this is a slight problem, because when the form is invalid, the page is redirected to `http://www.example.com/`

I am needing to keep this numeric value in the URL.

Is this possible?

I've looked at storing the value in a session, but this seems to be cleared everytime the URL changes.

Thanks

Comment: Can be helpful to see your action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, seems as simple as

```
if($form->isValid()){
  // do stuff 
} else {
  // invalid, then redirect
  $this->redirect('http://www.example.com/' . $request->getParameter('random_number'))
}
```

assuming you have a route like

```
formroute:
  url: /:random_number
  ....
```

Comment: that gives me an error: `The "/:number" route has some missing mandatory parameters (:number)`

Comment: Also, wouldn't i lose the validation errors since im redirecting?

Comment: Why do you want to use those random numbers after all?

Comment: The URLs are created by a 3rd party system, I need to capture the forms values, including the number string from the URL. This value is pretty important as the form values are bound to that value. So when the form fails validation, it is redirected to http://www.example.com so i lose the random number

Comment: I could do it using AJAX, but I'd rather not do that.